# работа с классами c++

Tags: c++

у меня есть два класса TMatrix(класс для работы с матрицами) и TVector(для работы с векторами)
в классе TMatrix у меня реализован метод умножения матрицы на вектор, но мне надо еще реализовать метод умножения вектора на матрицу, его я пытаюсь реализовать в классе TVector. в чем собственно проблема: в классе TMatrix у меня подключен класс вектора

```
#include"TVector.h"
```

но в классе TVector я не могу подключить TMatrix таким же способом, потому что зациклятся вызовы, вектор вызывает матрицу, а матрица вектор.
я подключал в векторе матрицу через friend class TMatrix, но метод все равно не понимает что такое TMatrix

```
 TVector operator *(TMatrix& T)
{
    TVector Res;
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            Res.Vector[j] += Vector[j] * T.GetMatrix(i, j);
        }
    }
    return Res;
}
```

программа говорит, что не знает что стоит слева от метода .GetMatrix(i, j), не может определить

```
double GetMatrix(int i, int j)
{
    if (i < 0 || i >= Ny)
    {
        throw "ERROR";
    }
    if (j < 0 || j >= Unit_Count)
    {
        throw "ERROR";
    }
    return matrix[i][j];
}
```

вот реализация метода GetMatrix.
При попытке собрать выдается ошибка, об использовании неопределенного типа TMatrix
как решить эту проблему?

[image]

на первой картинке в классе TVector объявляю класс TMatrix
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на второй картинке представлена реализация метода перемножения вектора на матрицу все в том же классе TVector, ругается на то, что подчеркнуто
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подключение класса TVector в классе TMatrix

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

просто так отключить вектор от матрицы не могу, так как есть достаточное количество методов, которые используют тип TVector, один из них на картинке

Comment: Есть хороший ответ, но я класс TVector  просто   сделал бы   членом класса(не другом)   TMatrix,

Answer (score 1):

Предшествующее неполное объявление типа (forward declaration) и указатели/ссылки.

Например:

B.h

```
class A;
class B {
    A *_a;
};
```

A.h

```
class B;
class A {
    B *_b;
};
```

Comment: я использовал предшествующее объявление, не помогло, все равно не видит, что такое TMatrix

Comment: @Jikukoda, имплементации нужно выносить в `*.cpp`, где делать include полных объявлений для зависимостей.

Comment: не получается, возможно, я что-то не так делаю

Comment: @Jikukoda, мы не узнаем, что вы делаете, пока вы не покажете код полностью

Comment: добавил скрины к вопросу, вряд ли нужен весь код целиком

Comment: @Jikukoda, C++ - это не Java и не C#, здесь принято объявления методов делать втутри объявления класса, а реализации (тела) выносить в `cpp`-файлы реализаций. Например [так](https://pastebin.com/92TUGE4c). Forward declaration помогает вам _ссылаться_ на объекты других типов, но чтобы делать выводы об их размере и составе (брать `sizeof`, использовать поля, вызывать методы и т.п.) необходимо полное определение. Такая ссылочная рекурсия разрывается вынесением всей конкретики в файл реализации.